# Auto inserting table name for subquery/join queries in Laravel (Eloquent)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here is my query:

```php
PHP
public function find(array $filter = []) : Collection
{
return $this->entity::where($filter)->join('cases_has_services', function ($join) {

        $join->on('cases_has_services.cases_id', 'checklists.cases_id');
        $join->on('cases_has_services.services_id', 'checklists.item_id');

    })->select('checklists.*', 'cases_has_services.quantity')->get();

}
```

i am receiving the next error:

```php
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where 
clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `checklists`.*, 
`cases_has_services`.`quantity` from `checklists` inner join 
`cases_has_services` on `cases_has_services`.`cases_id` = 
`checklists`.`cases_id` and `cases_has_services`.`services_id` = 
`checklists`.`item_id` where (`id` = 352))
```

So i fixed my code a little bit:

```php
public function find(array $filter = []) : Collection
{

    // TODO fix this
    foreach ($filter as $field => $value) {

        unset($filter[$field]);

        $field = 'checklists.' . $field;

        $filter[$field] = $value;

    }

    return $this->entity::where($filter)->join('cases_has_services', function ($join) {

        $join->on('cases_has_services.cases_id', 'checklists.cases_id');
        $join->on('cases_has_services.services_id', 'checklists.item_id');

    })->select('checklists.*', 'cases_has_services.quantity')->get();

}
```

But that is not a good practice i think. So, are there any native laravel path to auto insert table name in query with joins?
I mean, how to avoid using that part of code because its a little hacky:

```php
    foreach ($filter as $field => $value) {

        unset($filter[$field]);

        $field = 'checklists.' . $field;

        $filter[$field] = $value;

    }
```

Comment: what's the value of $filter?

Comment: @madalinivascu it's simple: ['id' => 123]

Comment: There is no built-in functionality for this.

Answer (score 0):

Change you $filter variable to:

`$filter = ['checklists.id' => 123]`